# Enzyme test for react component (shallow)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple react component that I want to test. It receives a callback via props.

```
<AnimalSelector onSearchTermChange={Search} />
```

It looks as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class SexSelector extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {sex: ''};
}
render(){
    return (<div>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male" checked={this.state.sex === 'male'} onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)} /> 
<label>Male</label>  
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female" checked={this.state.sex === 'female'} onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)} /> 
<label>Female</label>
</div>);        
}
onInputChange(animal){
    this.setState({sex});
    this.props.onSearchTermChange(sex);
}   
};
export default SexSelector
```

I wrote a simple test to check when the option changes:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import SexSelector from '../components/animal_selector';
it('male option changes state sex to male', () => {
const wrapper = shallow(<SexSelector onSearchTermChange="void()"/>); 
// manually trigger the callback
wrapper.instance().onInputChange('male');
expect(wrapper.state().sex).toBe('male');
});
```

However, the test runner throws the following error:

> TypeError: this.props.onSearchTermChange is not a function
> at SexSelector.onInputChange (src/components/sex_selector.js:20:15)
> at Object. (src/test/sexSelector.test.js:31:22)
> at node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16
> at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)

Is it possible with Jest/Enzyme to test a component without its parent? Which is the proper way to bypass the callback? Is this the correct approach for it?

Answer (score 1):

`"void()"` is just going to render as a string I think. Not an empty function. Either way it's not the best way to do it.

Instead of this, just pass a spy down.

I'm using [expect assertions](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) to create the spy here, you can use sinon or whatever you want instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import SexSelector from '../components/animal_selector';
import expect from 'expect';

it('male option changes state sex to male', () => {
    const spy = expect.createSpy();
    const wrapper = shallow(<SexSelector onSearchTermChange={spy} />); 
    const maleInput = wrapper.find('#male');
    const mockEvent = {};

    maleInput.simulate('change', mockEvent);

    expect(wrapper.state().sex).toBe('male');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockEvent);
});
```

Comment: it throws the following error:
TypeError: expect.createSpy is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/animalSelector.test.js:38:20)
      at node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)


However, I've tried the following approach, what do you think?

    it('dogs option changes state animal to dogs', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<AnimalSelector onSearchTermChange={()=>{} }/>); 
        wrapper.instance().onInputChange('dogs');
        expect(wrapper.state().animal).toBe('dogs');
    });

Comment: @grahamo'donnel That's not as robust, you are manually triggering the event instead of simulating it. I don't know why you are getting that error, what I posted is correct. Try and see the [expect documentation](https://github.com/mjackson/expect).